# Efficiency of using time_t and time_point in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

In C++, std::time_t and std::chrono::time_point are classes for storing date and time. Is it efficient to use time_point to store the time. It seems that time_point supports more functions, will it be less efficient while using it compared with time_t? About how large in memory size is an instance of time_point?  What's the size of instance of time_t?

Comment: does it really matter? are you allocating so many `time_point` structures that it becomes a memory bottleneck?

Comment: If size of time_point instance is large, the copying of time_point instances may highly affect the processing time if we use STL data structures which stores the classes containing time_point instances

Comment: then benchmark it. (if you didn't benchmark it, then chances are it doesn't matter that much.) By the way, the "copying" argument was probably justified a couple of decades ago, but nowadays cache misses and branch prediction failures dominate the bottlenecks.

Comment: from Mike's answer, it seems that I do not need to benchmark it :) Of course, we need benchmark it to confirm in practice.

Comment: For bottleneck, I agree that cahce misses and branch prediction failure may give an even more performance hit compared with copying. therefore, in addition to paying attention to size of a type, i will also try to avoid using branching and virtual function :)

Comment: For an efficient, type-safe, and easy-to-use open-source date library built on top of `time_point` see: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it efficient to use time_point to store the time.

Yes, it just contains a single numeric value.

> It seems that time_point supports more functions, will it be less efficient while using it compared with time_t?

Why would you think that? Non-virtual functions don't increase the object size, and simple ones should be inlined so that they can be as efficient as messing around with the numeric value directly.

> About how large in memory size is an instance of `time_point`?

The same size as the numeric type you told it to use. Probably 64 bits if you used one of the convenience duration types like `seconds`. Check with `sizeof` if it matters.

> What's the size of instance of time_t?

Unspecified, typically 32 or 64 bits. Check with `sizeof` if it matters. If it's 32, then you might run into trouble in a couple of decades' time.